# How to setup a local POP3 server?

Tags: software-rec, email

I'm developing a Thunderbird extension and I would like to setup a fake POP3 account to play with. What's the easiest way to setup a local POP3 server? It doesn't need to be particularly secure/robust, as it's meant only for local testing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dovecot or Courier is probably your best bet.

- http://wiki2.dovecot.org/POP3Server
- http://www.courier-mta.org/install.html#pop3

Comment: dovecot is great stuff.